# ng-hide doesn't remove from class after a asyncronous apiService call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array in my scope populated by a service call triggered from a `ui-select`:

```
<ui-select search-enabled="true" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.ClubOrganization" ng-change="$parent.ClubOrganization_Change()" theme="select2" append-to-body="true"></ui-select>
```

---

```
$scope.TeamTypes = undefined;

$scope.ClubOrganization_Change = function () {
    $scope.GetClubTeamTypes();
};
$scope.GetClubTeamTypes = function () {
    $scope.GetTeamTypes($scope.CurrentUser.ClubOrganization.OrganizationId);
};
$scope.GetTeamTypes = function (organizationId) {
    apiService.GetTeamTypes(organizationId).success(function (response) {
        $scope.TeamTypes = response;

    });
};
```

---

```
<div class="block block-bordered" ng-hide="{{$parent.TeamTypes.length == undefined}}">
    <div class="block-header bg-gray-lighter">
        <h3 class="block-title">Teams</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="typeTeams">
            <span ng-repeat="typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes">
                <md-checkbox aria-label="{{typeTeam.TypeName}}">
                    <label>{{typeTeam.TypeName}}</label>
                </md-checkbox>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the `ng-repeat="typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes"` works as expected, however the `ng-hide="{{$parent.TeamTypes.length == undefined}}"` doesn't works.
This is the renderized result:

```
<div class="block block-bordered ng-hide" ng-hide="false" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="typeTeams">
            <!-- ngRepeat: typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes --><span ng-repeat="typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes" class="ng-scope">
                <md-checkbox aria-label="Team A" flex="" role="checkbox" class="flex"><div class="md-container md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="md-icon"></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="md-label">
                    <label class="ng-binding ng-scope">Team A</label>
                </div></md-checkbox>
            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes --><span ng-repeat="typeTeam in $parent.TeamTypes" class="ng-scope">
                <md-checkbox aria-label="Under 21" flex="" role="checkbox" class="flex"><div class="md-container md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="md-icon"></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="md-label">
                    <label class="ng-binding ng-scope">Under 21</label>
                </div></md-checkbox>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How you can see, the `ng-repeat` works, and the `ng-hide` attribute is false, but `ng-hide` class is still in the class attribute:

```
<div class="block block-bordered ng-hide" ng-hide="false" aria-hidden="true">
```

I thought it was the fault of the asyncronous apiService call, so I changed my $scope.GetTeamTypes method this make an $apply():

```
$scope.GetTeamTypes = function (organizationId) {
        apiService.GetTeamTypes(organizationId).success(function (response) {
            $scope.TeamTypes = response;
            $scope.$apply();
        });

    };
```

but when the $scope.ClubOrganization_Change is triggered I retrieve this error:

```
angular.js:12416 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at angular.js:68
    at beginPhase (angular.js:16235)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15976)
    at userModalController.js:222
    at angular.js:10215
    at processQueue (angular.js:14634)
    at angular.js:14650
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15689)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15986)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-hide`/`ng-show` should not have `{{}}` in their expression value, you could simplify it to below.

```
ng-hide="!$parent.TeamTypes.length"
```

> **Note**: Using `$parent` while referring to scope variable on HTML, isn;t consider as good practice, do use `controllerAs` pattern **OR** `Dot rule` while defining models.

Comment: @Infer-On pleased to know that it helped.. Thanks :-)